# Using Loader to display data in an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-alertdialog, loader

I am looking for a way to display some data that are retrieved with a loader from an SQLite DB in an `AlertDialog`. Clicking a name in a `ListView` will transfer the DB entry ID to the `DialogFragment`, and based on this, additional data should be loaded.
The loading as such does work but it seems to happen after the `AlertDialog` is displayed because the message box only shows Null as a value. Does anybody know if it is possible at all to transfer data into a `AlertDialog` like this? Thanks for your help!

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;


@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") 
public class BirthdayDetailsMessage extends DialogFragment implements
LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    static String DATE_FORMAT;
    static final String CALENDAR = "calendar";

    private long mRowId;
    private String mName;
    private String mDate;
    private boolean mYearKnown;
    private String mAge;
    private Calendar mCalendar;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();        

        DATE_FORMAT = PrefDateFormat.getPrefDateFormat(getActivity());

        Bundle arguments = getArguments();

        mRowId = arguments.getLong(ReminderProvider.COLUMN_ROWID); 

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);  
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){   

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setMessage("Birthday: "+ mDate +"\n\n"+"Age: "+ mAge)
        .setTitle(mName)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            dialog.cancel();    
                    }               
                }); 

       return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                ReminderProvider.CONTENT_URI, mRowId), null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor reminder) {

        if (reminder.getCount() == 0) {
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((OnFinishEditor) getActivity()).finishEditor();
                }
            });
            return;
        }

        mName = reminder.getString(reminder
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ReminderProvider.COLUMN_NAME));

        mYearKnown = (reminder.getInt(reminder
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ReminderProvider.COLUMN_YEAR))==0? false:true);

        Long dateInMillis = reminder.getLong(reminder
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ReminderProvider.COLUMN_DATE));
        Date date = new Date(dateInMillis);
        mCalendar.setTime(date); 

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        mDate = dateFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());

        if (mYearKnown == true){
            mAge = String.valueOf(GetDiffYears.getDiffYears(mCalendar));
        }else{
            mAge = "age not known";
        }        

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        // nothing to reset for this fragment
    }   

}
```

EDIT:

I removed the onCreateDialog method and used the following View instead

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, container,
            false);
    getDialog().setTitle("Name");   

    Date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
    Age = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.age);


    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    return v;
}

private void updateValues() {
    getDialog().setTitle(mName);
    Date.setText("Geburtstag: "+ mDate);
    Age.setText("Alter: " + mAge);      
}
```

In included updateValues() in onLoadFinished, and created an layout XML for the message body...this way it seems to work properly.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how possible it will be to make this work. Since the data is being loaded in a background thread, the UI continues to set up the dialog, using null values since the background thread hasn't finished. If you froze the UI thread to wait for the background thread, the values wouldn't be null, but you never want to lock the UI thread. My suggestion is to create an AsyncTask when the listview item is clicked and load your data there, then in the onPostExecute method, create your dialog.

Comment: your answer is in your question. You making Dialog before loading. Use Async as suggested by Joseph Roque

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick help...I am sure this is the right way to get the initial code running, howere I never worked with Async yet and had a look at it, and I am afraid it will take me some time to get familiar with it. Since the loader always worked properly when I used an inflated view I tried to work around by using a custom DialogFragment which is inflated, see EDIT....it works.

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is use a call back method from your `Loader` to create the dialog. I would not put the `Loader` in the dialog class, but either in the calling class or as a separate class. Then call/create the dialog in `onLoadFinished`. The implementation would be similar with `AsyncTask`.

Alternately, you could create the dialog with some default text, and retain a reference to it in your calling class. Then in your `onLoadFinished` update the values of the dialog. I'm pretty sure that one would work, but I haven't tested it.